# I've got an error when i'm going to start to play 'Bully: Scholarship Edition'

Tags: wine, games

When I launch the game I can see main menu of one. But a window with error is showed after I press 'Story' in this menu.
Here is the error:

```
Unhandled exception: unimplemented function vcomp.dll._vcomp_fork called in 32-bit code (0x7b83aace).
Register dump:
 CS:0073 SS:007b DS:007b ES:007b FS:0033 GS:003b
 EIP:7b83aace ESP:0032f3b4 EBP:0032f428 EFLAGS:00200283(   - --  I S - - -C)
 EAX:7b82695d EBX:7b8b5000 ECX:00000008 EDX:0032f3d4
 ESI:80000100 EDI:00000a28
Stack dump:
0x0032f3b4:  0032f450 00000008 7bc37239 80000100
0x0032f3c4:  00000001 00000000 7b83aace 00000002
0x0032f3d4:  7dea5524 7dea5abd 0040295c 3ecd468e
0x0032f3e4:  bec74468 0032f404 080b3430 02f885c0
0x0032f3f4:  0075f509 02f885c0 080b3508 02f885c0
0x0032f404:  080b3430 00771a79 080b3430 02f885c0
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7b83aace in kernel32 (+0x2aace) (0x0032f428)
  1 0x7dea5508 in vcomp (+0x5507) (0x0032f460)
  2 0x7dea46f5 in vcomp (+0x46f4) (0x7b834bf0)
  3 0x004026d4 in bully (+0x26d3) (0x7b834bf0)
  4 0xfff0e483 (0x04244c8d)
0x7b83aace: subl    $4,%esp
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (130 modules)
PE    330000-  346000   Deferred        xinput1_3
PE    400000- 20f3000   Export          bully
PE   2100000- 24c8000   Deferred        d3dx9_38
ELF 79e46000-7b800000   Deferred        libllvm-3.4.so.1
ELF 7b800000-7ba5b000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba5b000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcdb000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcdb000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7bffa000-7c012000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7c012000-7c01b000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 7c01b000-7c047000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7c047000-7c1bf000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 7c1bf000-7c231000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7c231000-7c2a0000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-4.0.so
ELF 7c2a0000-7c2ef000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7c404000-7c438000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 7c438000-7c43f000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7c43f000-7c449000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF 7c463000-7c48b000   Deferred        winepulse<elf>
  \-PE  7c470000-7c48b000   \               winepulse
ELF 7c48b000-7c4ad000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c490000-7c4ad000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7c4ad000-7c4f6000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7c4b0000-7c4f6000   \               dsound
ELF 7c4f6000-7c521000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7c500000-7c521000   \               msacm32
ELF 7c521000-7c5db000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7c530000-7c5db000   \               winmm
ELF 7c66c000-7c6b7000   Deferred        dinput<elf>
  \-PE  7c670000-7c6b7000   \               dinput
ELF 7c8c5000-7c902000   Deferred        d3d9<elf>
  \-PE  7c8d0000-7c902000   \               d3d9
ELF 7cd12000-7d0ed000   Deferred        libgallium.so.0
ELF 7d22f000-7d254000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d240000-7d254000   \               imm32
ELF 7d27b000-7d286000   Deferred        libjson-c.so.2
ELF 7d30e000-7d345000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7d345000-7d367000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.5
ELF 7d367000-7d36e000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7d36e000-7d38b000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7d474000-7d482000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7d482000-7d49a000   Deferred        libelf.so.1
ELF 7d49a000-7d884000   Deferred        r600_dri.so
ELF 7d884000-7d88d000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d88d000-7d8d8000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d8d8000-7d8e2000   Deferred        libnih-dbus.so.1
ELF 7d8e2000-7d8fb000   Deferred        libnih.so.1
ELF 7d8fb000-7d919000   Deferred        libcgmanager.so.0
ELF 7d919000-7d92c000   Deferred        libudev.so.1
ELF 7d92c000-7d939000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7d939000-7d93c000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7d93c000-7d943000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7d943000-7d947000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7d947000-7d94b000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7d94b000-7d951000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7d951000-7d969000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7d969000-7d96c000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7d96c000-7d970000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7d970000-7d9d0000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7d9ea000-7da21000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7d9f0000-7da21000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7da21000-7da27000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7da27000-7da32000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7da32000-7da43000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7da43000-7da47000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7da47000-7da52000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7da52000-7da5d000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7da5d000-7da63000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7da63000-7da67000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7da67000-7da6e000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7da6e000-7da72000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7da72000-7da94000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7da94000-7dbc8000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7dbc8000-7dbdb000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7dbdb000-7dbf3000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7dbf5000-7dc87000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7dc00000-7dc87000   \               winex11
ELF 7dd16000-7dd3f000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7dd3f000-7dd7a000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dd7a000-7dda2000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7dda2000-7ddbc000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7ddbc000-7de5c000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7de76000-7de92000   Deferred        dinput8<elf>
  \-PE  7de80000-7de92000   \               dinput8
ELF 7de92000-7deaa000   Dwarf           vcomp<elf>
  \-PE  7dea0000-7deaa000   \               vcomp
ELF 7deaa000-7df52000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7dec0000-7df52000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7df52000-7e088000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7df70000-7e088000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e088000-7e1c4000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e0a0000-7e1c4000   \               ole32
ELF 7e1c4000-7e2cb000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e1d0000-7e2cb000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e2cb000-7e345000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e2e0000-7e345000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e345000-7e578000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e350000-7e578000   \               shell32
ELF 7e578000-7e5f9000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e580000-7e5f9000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e5f9000-7e66a000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e600000-7e66a000   \               setupapi
ELF 7e6a0000-7e7fa000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e6b0000-7e7fa000   \               user32
ELF 7e7fa000-7e86c000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e810000-7e86c000   \               advapi32
ELF 7e86c000-7e989000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e880000-7e989000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e989000-7ea98000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9b0000-7ea98000   \               opengl32
ELF 7ea98000-7ebd8000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7eab0000-7ebd8000   \               wined3d
ELF 7ebd8000-7ec4d000   Deferred        ddraw<elf>
  \-PE  7ebe0000-7ec4d000   \               ddraw
ELF 7ef7f000-7ef8c000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef8c000-7ef98000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef98000-7efb1000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7efb1000-7efba000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7efba000-7f000000   Deferred        libm.so.6
PE  7fd40000-7fd7b000   Deferred        xactengine3_1
PE  7fd80000-7fe08000   Deferred        xaudio2_1
ELF b7433000-b75e2000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF b75e2000-b75e7000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF b75e8000-b7604000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF b7604000-b761e000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  b7610000-b761e000   \               version
ELF b761e000-b77d3000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF b77d5000-b77f7000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF b77f7000-b77f8000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) Z:\home\mv\.wine\drive_c\Games\Bully - Scholarship Edition\Bully.exe
    0000002e    0
    0000002d   15
    0000002c   15
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028   15
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000009    0 <==
0000000e services.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    00000019    0
    00000018    0
    00000016    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001d    0
    0000001a    0
    00000017    0
    00000013    0
0000001b plugplay.exe
    00000021    0
    00000020    0
    0000001c    0
00000022 explorer.exe
    00000024    0
    00000023    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.6.2
    Platform: i386
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.13.0-43-generic
```